# Why do UID on server and client have to match when using cifs?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I connect from a linux client with one user (1000) to a server.

**The username is the same on both machines, but has a different UID.**

When I connect the files show up as owned by `1001` and not as `USER` as I would expect. I would expect cifs to translate the original user to the one I use on the client. But this is not the case. It seems that I have to have similar users on both client and server and also have them assigned the same UID on both. But I can not imagine that this is the only solution to it.

The client has mount.cifs version 6.4.

My fstab is

`//192.168.111.190/hgst /home/ben/hgst cifs vers=1.0,noauto,users,uid=1001,username=USER,password=PASSWORD`.

I already changed it to include `vers=1.0` and `uid=1001`.

The [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) sais that I might use `forceuid` on the client to force a certain user. If I include this option into my fstab I get an `invalid argument` upon `mount`, both with 1000 and 1001. I don't use `forceuid` on the server.

My server is running openmediavault 3 and my client is Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu?   You haven't mentioned a release, and haven't used a Ubuntu man page (eg. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.cifs.8.html) but a non-Ubuntu page that may not relate to your unspecified release of Ubuntu (if you are using Ubuntu). If you are using Ubuntu, you should be using ubuntu man pages, and a release that matches your system (eg. my example is for xenial/16.04)

Comment: This helped me a lot!

Comment: Are you aware Lubuntu 16.04 LTS reached EOL earlier this year?  Flavors of Ubuntu only have 3 years of support, so 16.04 or 2016-April + 3 years = 2019.April, with only Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with Unity, server [no gui] or Kylin) still receiving support. Yes some of your system is supported, but not GUI components from 'universe' so please consider upgrading.  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I upgraded to Lubuntu 18 on one machine and I did not like a lot of changes that where made, including the graphics and behaviour of the panel. I will stick to 16 as long as possible in any way. In my experience it is the best OS with an awesome clean layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THe UID on the server and client do not have to match. That is the whole reason you would use a samba server.

It's sorta kinda like mounting an NTFS partition. Without a uid specification the mounted share would be owned by root. The uid=1001 refers to the uid of the user on the **client** not the server if the client has a user with that uid.

TO THE SERVER: Everything you do is done as the user you logged in with in the username=USER / password=PASSWORD combination in your cifs mount expression regardless of how you mounted it in the client.

TO THE CLIENT: If the client is Linux it will mount with however you defined it in your mount expression.

And there is no need for a forceuid parameter.

So this is what it should have been:

```
//192.168.100.90/hgst /home/ben/Benshare/hgst cifs vers=1.0,noauto,users,uid=1000,username=USER,password=PASSWORD
```

**EDIT**

The uid parameter in a CIFS mount expression changes ownership of the mounted share from root to the one specified by uid. In your original mount you set uid to 1001 which is for a user that doesn't exist on the client. You should have set uid to 1000 because that is the uid of the client user. forceuid should not be required.

Comment: The problem is that the login with username=ben will be done with UID 1000 since ben has 1000 on the client. Then ben will not have write permissions to the server that has files owned by UID 1001 on it (which is username ben on the server). Hence the need for forceuid. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work as you described it. "username=ben" refers to the user ben ( with his associated uid number ) on the server not the client. It's true that without a uid reference in the mount expression you will not have write access since it will be owned by root. But the uid reference needs to be the uid of the client user. CIFS is a virtual filesystem.

Comment: But if I use it with `username=ben` only then it will display the files on the client side as owned by `1001`. Since there is no user with that ID on the client side there is no name for it.

Comment: I can't reproduce that affect. If you ran it without any uid reference if should be owned by root and unwriteable to anyone on the client. Just by changing "uid=1001" to "uid=1000" should have fixed this if that is the uid on the client. Between Linux permissions on the server and multiple ways to to configure a samba share it may be possible to reproduce your symptom but I can't think of a scenario at the moment. I would change the uid reference to 1000 if that is the client users uid number and add nounix to the mix of options rather than forceuid.

Comment: Yes that was the case, it was read-only. But I don't understand your reference to root. If it would be owned by root it should be writable, no? I fixed the issue as I stated in my own answer using forceuid. I would not understand what benefit nounix would bring.

Comment: I added my response to my original answer. Then I'm going to stop. I'm going to get yelled at soon for making too many comments. You found a solution that works for you and that's great.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do UID on server and client have to match when using cifs?

No idea. Should not be the case though. It should take a username on 1 end and a username on the other end if those are the same. 
Mind this:

> uid=arg
>
> sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0. The mount.cifs helper must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in non-numeric form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND PERMISSIONS below for more information.

...

> The username is the same on both machines, but has a different UID.

If those are the same why not use the username? `uid` accepts both a name and a user id.

> The manual sais that I might use forceuid on the client to force a certain user.

You would use `user=` or `uid=` with a username or `credentials=` with a filename that has a username and password before `forceuid`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But beware that you made the same mistake as I did. Forceuid is just an option without argument, e.g. without `=`.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was, that I was using `forceuid` the **wrong way**.

The option has to be included like this:

```
uid=1000,forceuid
```

Meaning I had to set a `uid` first and then put the option `forceuid` without an argument to make sure the UID from the other option is used.

I cross-checked this with the ownership on the server. The files are now displayed on the client with UID 1000 but written to the server with UID 1001, exacly how it should be. The username is the same, which is also correct.

---

My other error was to state the UID as the one from the server (1001). But it has to be the other way around, the **UID needs to tell the client which local user should own the files**, in my case `uid=1000`.

So, with that option, `forceuid` is probably not necessary.

---

The usefull man page was: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.cifs.8.html